# Вопрос "Теория вероятностей"

Tags: математика, комбинаторика, теория-вероятностей, динамическое-программирование

Помогите решить задачу:

> Игральный кубик бросается N раз. Найдите вероятность того, что сумма N бросков равно Q.
>   Входные данные: N, Q. (Целые числа)
>   Выходные данные: 10^-6 точность..

Вот задачи:

1) Вход: 1 6
Вывод: 0,166667
2) Вход: 1 7
Вывод: 0,000000
3) Вход: 4 14
Вывод: 0,112654

Рыл книгу свою "Высшая математика" не нашел подобного. Везде "Найти вероятность выпадания 6, четных и т.п".

Comment: При каждом броске выпадает только **одно** число. Как вы собираетесь получить 14 при каждом из 4 бросков одного кубика? Вы явно неверно дали условие...

Comment: @Harry изменил, мой косяк...

Comment: Читать надо не тервер, а комбинаторику. N бросков, все есссно независимые, возможная сумма от N до 6N, каждая со своим количеством вариантов. Есть и прямая формула. Вот её и следует найти да закодить. А вероятность - это поделить на общее количество вариантов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ладно, смотрите простенькое решение. Всего вариантов выпадений кубика - 6*6*...*6 = 6^N.

Сколько наших? Обзовем эту функцию как PQ(Q,N) - Q очков за N бросков.

Первый кубик - может выпасть 1...6, так что получается, что надо просуммировать все варианты:

```
PQ(Q,N) = P(Q-1,N-1)+P(Q-2,N-1)+...P(Q-6,N-1)
```

Вот и рекуррентная формула. Накладывая на нее естественные ограничения - типа, при 0 бросков - ноль выпадений, сумма очков не может быть меньше N и больше 6N и так далее, можем написать такой код:

```
unsigned long long PQ(int Q, int N)
{
    if (Q <= 0) return 0;
    if (N <= 0) return 0;
    if (Q < N || Q > 6*N) return 0;
    if (N == 1) return 1;
    unsigned long long sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 6; ++i)
    {
        sum += PQ(Q-i,N-1);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

При реально больших N и Q считать будет неимоверно долго, но тут уж примените мемоизацию или восходящее динамическое программирование сами...

Вот [программа](https://ideone.com/AayzHY), которая, используя эту функцию, выводит искомые вероятности - как у вас в условии...